# Registration Approval by Admin

Tags: plugins, module, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm looking for a joomla plugin or module that does the Registration Approval by Admin like the following one: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/10737

I tested it but it didn't work, so please is there any one like it that works for Joomla 1.5?

Comment: Manoel are you looking for a module that provide the facility of user registration and the registration is approved by admin...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the user settings to disable account activation. This way you have to enable the user before they can login.

There is not another extension at the moment that does what that one does - perhaps you could post how it did not work and maybe there is someone here who knows how to correct the issue.